# SSL: should be an index file in .well-known folder?

Tags: ssl

many SSL certificate require a small text file placed in a folder in the public_html directory (.well-known and sub directory).
Should I place an empty index.php, for example, in that folder to avoid people see the file?

Comment: In my experience, the ssl certificate files are not in the public directory where the site would be delivered from. It's been awhile since I've worked with that though - my shared host handles it for me. You could use a `.htaccess` and deny all requests. I don't remember how to do that either though.

Comment: Hello, the certificate is not in a public directory but the small text file is